# How can I disable the screen lock password in lollipop?

Tags: lock-screens, security, 5.0-lollipop

I have enabled password protection on the lock screen on my Nexus 5 Lollipop device:

[image]

**After enabling password, I can't seem to be able to cancel it. Any idea how to go back to <kbd>None</kbd> or <kbd>Swipe</kbd>?**

Comment: Just a suggestion, can you try this?
Select `Pattern` > Choose and confirm a pattern > And then check if `Swipe` gets enabled.

Comment: In my case **None was missing** entirely, I only had the four options Swipe, Pattern, PIN, Password.  Deleting guest and cycling power (and possibly other actions) brought it back.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This works at my device:

Settings -> Security -> Deactivate Administrators. Deactivate anything listed.

Settings -> Security -> Clear credentials.

Comment: I didn't need to deactivate any administrators and just needed to clear credentials

Comment: Comment left by an anonymous user: "If this doesn't work you need to do this as well: Open notification bar, then go to Users, then Remove Guest."

Comment: For android 6.0 on my phone, this wasn't enough. I used a 'hack' I found on a forum: set up an unlock pattern with a recovery code, lock the phone, fail the pattern on purpose multiple times and then after the one-minute waiting period, use the recovery code to log in. It takes you to security settings, after removing the screen lock *on its own*.

Answer (score 11):

You can simply erase you security credentials in security and this will automatically allow you to remove the lock screen on 5.0

Comment: This is good, but please provide more specific directions

Answer (score 1):

Check if your credentials in security, if you have an application that requires you to have a password and delete that.

Did you encrypt the phone ? That requires a password.

Also if you are a guest you cant, but i think you already are an administrator of your own device.