# I can't remove my lock screen

Tags: nexus-5

I cannot disable lock screen. When I try to go to settings -->security-->screen lock the none option is not there it has just been disappeared. 
I have a nexus 5 with android 5.1 build number lrx2cc

Comment: Is your device encrypted? Do you have a VPN or an Exchange Server account set up?

Answer (score 0):

Try Factory resetting your phone.

Switch off the phone and power on by holding volume up key and power key at once,this will take you to other setting something like bios of the phone, hope you find something usefull there

Comment: Factory reset for something like unable to remove the lock screen seems a bit extreme. I feel factory reset should be "last resort"

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a duplicate of [How can I disable the screen lock password in lollipop?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/88306/how-can-i-disable-the-screen-lock-password-in-lollipop)

Basically, you should be able to go to:
Settings -> Security -> Deactivate Administrators. Then deactivate anything listed.

Next, go to:
Settings -> Security -> Clear credentials.

It should work now.